# Remove session cookie in login form with Flask application

Tags: cookies, flask

I'm working on simple a Flask application that has two parts; first part is Login form (`login.html`) where the user must fill some ID number. When the Submit button is pressed the ID number is stored into a cookie and the second page (`index.html`) is rendered.

I observed undesired behavior: when I reload the second page, the first page with Login form is properly rendered (and cookie is removed). However, if I press reload button *again*, the second page is loaded with cookie.

I kindly as for any advice how to remove cookie is this setting.

The Flask file goes as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'abc'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if session.get('logged_in') is None:
            session['id_number'] = request.form['id_number']
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return render_template('index.html')
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Here is also the main part of the `login.html` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function (e) {    
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: '/logout',
    data: { IsRefresh: 'Close' }
   });
};
</script>
<form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="id_number" id="id_number">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use `return redirect(url_for('index', var=var))` in place of `return 
render_template('index.html')`, Furthermore you must check this [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668481/difference-between-render-template-and-redirect) , There is a difference between rendering templates and using redirect function.